# Facebook's Lint is crawling root URL rather than the given URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

There are previous posts about this on the web, however none of the proposed solutions actually work for my scenario.

I have a children pages which all have their own unique og tags, and a parent root domain page with its own og tag, all to be crawled by facebook so people can see the descriptions/images when they are posted.

However, when I post my child url in the box, the results are blatantly proof that facebook crawled the parent page instead. Even the "see exactly what our **scraper** sees" page confirms that because it is only the parent template being shown.

Here is a link to fb's **scraper** : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Here are my og tags in the root domain html template:
Suppose the parent is [www.me.com](http://www.me.com)
Suppose one child is  [www.me.com/path/path](http://www.me.com/path/path)

```
<head> ...

    <meta name="keywords" content="...">

    <meta name="description" content="..." />

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:description" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.me.com" />
```

Here are the og tags in the child html template:

```
<head> ...

    <meta name="keywords" content="...">

    <meta name="description" content="..." />

    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="..."/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:description" content="..." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.me.com/path/path" />
```

This is very frustrating because i've tried removing and adding many of the tags in different combinations, and every single time, the [www.me.com](http://www.me.com) parent gets crawled, while the child is left ignored!!

I tried to mimic the order of the tags of other sites with this feature working like cnn.com, but however mine still refuse to crawl the child..

Any help? Thank you.

Comment: how can I add more points to this bounty?

Comment: You have an app id there: do you have an app? Does it have a canonical URL?

Comment: yes I do, i set both the "site url" and the "domain" tot he root url if that is causing any problems.

Comment: In your app, do you set/manipulate the object URL? That's what is used for the scraping, I think...

Comment: I have not, they were originally django template vars, but I just hardcoded them to see if it will failed, it still did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue after after finally noticing some odd hints. The site i'm working on is set so the first page view redirects to a splash page if and only if a specific cookie has not been set.

Hence, the Facebook crawler was hitting that page every time. It was not obvious though because the splash page inherits so much and looks just like one of the regular child pages.

What an unfortunate & time consuming bug.

Answer (score 3):

Check that you're not

- Rejecting the crawler's attempt to reach the child page
- Redirecting the child page to the parent page when the crawler tries to load it
- Including an og:url meta tag on the child page pointing to the homepage
- Including a canonical meta tag in the child page pointing to the parent

Those are by far the most likely reasons for this, and though you've said in your question your og:url tags are correct, in my experience that's most likely to be the problrm

Comment: Im not doing any of that

Comment: i removed the templating language and hardcoded the url tags, they still don't work

Comment: "Rejecting the crawler's attempt to reach the child page
Redirecting the child page to the parent page when the crawler tries to load it" can you elaborate on what your first two points mean?

Comment: Check what you're returning to Facebook's request, make sure it's not an error or redirect page, and that the response you do return doesn't have an og:url tag pointing to a different URL, or that you don't have a canonical meta tag pointing to a different URL

Comment: I clicked "see exactly what our scrapper sees" on facebook's lint debug tool, oddly enough what I saw was exactly identical to the parent/root url, NOT the url which was supposed to be fetched (child).

Comment: I did the same exact as above but with the og:url missing from the child, same result. Both my parent and child have og tags, however they are different, maybe that can cause something?

Comment: perhaps type=article is causing an issue? i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

This may be a stupid question, but I'll ask it nonetheless: Do the child urls have public access? The problem you are facing could be because the child url is being redirected to root url.

In the facebook linter output check for **Fetched Url** and **Canonical Url** section. This will give you some idea, whether redirections are happening.

Comment: This is very frustrating. The canon vs fetched url's are different. Canon for whatever reason is the root domain url, fetched is some child url which we actually want data from... As a result all the data which is supposed to be of the child is getting pulled from the parent!!!!

Comment: what does 'public access' mean? i can visit any page fine on via request/browser

Comment: in the child template I viewed the source and the tags were proper, I paste into lint, bam they are only getting parent tags

Comment: By public access I mean, any outside party can view the child document  without any authentication required. If your child page requires authenticated access, the facebook crawler will not be able to access the child page, as it will be redirected to the parent page.

Comment: If you want to check this, install [REST client for CHROME](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon). Use the tool to request your child url and check what response it gets.

Answer (score 0):

It's Facebook....  there's something in their 'cacheing' or whatever you want to call it.... 
when a page is registered with a incorrect url... correcting that can be tricky....if not impossible...

Just try this.... change your back page url to:
www.me.com/path/path/file1.php
and run it thru the linter....with the correct metatags.....